# .NET 7 removes empty string from the array loaded from appsettings in unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-7.0, appsettings

In the appsettings is an array with an empty string in it. I run the API and get the value by calling `config.GetSection("AppSettings").GetSection("Mapping").Get<string[][]>()`

The result in this case is fine, an array with 2 values and inside of both are 3 values.

Result in the API:

[image]

Sample of appsettings:

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "Mapping": [
      [ "yes", true, 1 ],
      [ "", false, -1 ]
    ]
  }
}
```

### Unit test

The problem is in the unit test. I load the same appsettings but the entry with the empty string was removed.

[image]

I changed the project back to .NET 6 and all is fine. So something has changed in .NET 7, but i can't find what and how i can prevent it from being deleted.
In the following unit test are two instances of IConfiguration. The first one configurationRoot works fine, there are 2 entries with 3 entries inside, also the empty string. The second one config has 2 entries and the second entry has only 2 entries, the empty string was removed and the check fails.

It's very strange, because the source of config is configurationRoot. For me, this indicates that the clone of configurationRoot was changed in TestServer. In my case, that's bad.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Xunit;

namespace TestProject1
{
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            IConfigurationRoot configurationRoot = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("UnitTestAppConfig.json")
                .Build();

            TestServer server = new(new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseEnvironment("Development")
                .UseConfiguration(configurationRoot)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
            );
            IConfiguration? config = server.Services.GetService<IConfiguration>();

            string[][] mappingFromConfigBuilder = configurationRoot.GetSection("AppSettings").GetSection("Mapping").Get<string[][]>();
            string[][] mappingFromTestServer = config.GetSection("AppSettings").GetSection("Mapping").Get<string[][]>();

            Assert.Equal(2, mappingFromConfigBuilder.Length);
            Assert.Equal(2, mappingFromTestServer.Length);

            Assert.Equal(3, mappingFromConfigBuilder[1].Length);
            Assert.Equal(3, mappingFromTestServer[1].Length); // <= Fails here
        }
    }

    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) { }
        public void Configure() { }
    }
}
```

Used NuGet packages

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost
- Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk
- xunit
- xunit.runner.visualstudio

I also tried with older versions of the packages, but that had no effect.

Does anyone have an idea what i can do? I will not change the source in the API, that works fine, only the unit test has a problem.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: What are you testing here? My first instinct was to say just mock external dependencies like the Configuration subsystem away. But that seems to be the thing you test.

Comment: The unit test is only an easy sample. In real it's a test for an API controller, called by server.sendAsync. When instantiating from the controller, the configuration is passed, the result is the same as in the unit test above.

Answer (score 0):

It's a issue related with WebHostBuilder

Since you're working with .net 7,you may try  without startup such as:

```
TestServer server = new(IServiceProvider);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, i will try it